# TM package in R error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, twitter, package, tm

I'm sorry if this is a pretty basic question, but I have been trying to use the TM package in R and the `content_transformation(tolower))` function does not work. I have updated all packages, spent hours trying to solve the problem with google but it just does not work.
Here's my code:

```
Access key and code for entering Twitter API (I will not show my credentials here)
library("twitteR")
library("stringr")
library("dplyr")
library("stringi")
library("tm")

tweets.1 <- userTimeline("GobiernodeChile", n = 1000)
tweets.1.df <- twListToDF(tweets.1)
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(tweets.1.df$text))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
```

Here's the error that R shows up after the last line

```
Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Here a peak of the data structure

```
> dput(head(tweets.1.df))
structure(list(text = c("Con la fuerza del lápiz puedes cambiar la historia 
de nuestro país. En la segunda vuelta del 17 de diciembre, ejerc… 
HU913G9RI1", 
"#ChileMejor: oportunidades laborales sin distinciones <ed><U+00A0><U+00BD>
<ed><U+00B1><U+00A9><ed><U+00A0><U+00BC><ed><U+00BF><U+00BD><ed><U+00A0>
<U+00BD><ed><U+00B1><U+00B4><ed><U+00A0><U+00BC><ed><U+00BF><U+00BD>. La 
#LeyInclusiónLaboral entrega dignidad y protección s… 
/hpuPinbieA", 
"¿Definiendo qué carrera estudiar? #DecídetePorPedagogía y conoce las nuevas 
condiciones para la docencia ¡mejores r… /edLskB99kg", 
"Este año, por primera vez en la historia de <ed><U+00A0><U+00BC><ed>
<U+00B7><U+00A8><ed><U+00A0><U+00BC><ed><U+00B7><U+00B1> más de 39 mil 
personas tuvieron derecho a ejercer el #VotoExterior e… 
/jKL021IzM1", 
"Con la aprobación del #Presupuesto2018 se puede disponer de más recursos y 
nuevas instituciones para trabajar en fa… ", 
"¡Un aporte y reconocimiento para los adultos mayores! <ed><U+00A0><U+00BC>
<ed><U+00BE><U+0085><ed><U+00A0><U+00BC><ed><U+00BE><U+0084> El Aguinaldo 
Navideño 2017 beneficiará a dos millones de p… "
), favorited = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), favoriteCount = 
c(56, 
42, 14, 103, 17, 26), replyToSN = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
created = structure(c(1512248324, 1512219549, 1512154009, 
1512152828, 1512140997, 1512136218), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), truncated = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), replyToSID = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
id = c("937063508797161472", "936942814474264576", "936667921409105920", 
"936662968837779458", "936613346215854082", "936593300697608193"
), replyToUID = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), statusSource = c("<a 
href=\//studio.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Media Studio</a>", 
"<a href=\"ttp://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>", 
"<a href=\"ttp://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>", 
"<a href=\"ttps://studio.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Media Studio</a>", 
"<a href=\"ttp://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>", 
"<a href=\"ttp://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>"
), screenName = c("GobiernodeChile", "GobiernodeChile", "GobiernodeChile", 
"GobiernodeChile", "GobiernodeChile", "GobiernodeChile"), 
retweetCount = c(59, 55, 15, 100, 21, 28), isRetweet = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), retweeted = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), longitude = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), latitude = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("text", 
"favorited", "favoriteCount", "replyToSN", "created", "truncated", 
"replyToSID", "id", "replyToUID", "statusSource", "screenName", 
"retweetCount", "isRetweet", "retweeted", "longitude", "latitude"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Can anyone assist a lost soul?
    Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please add the output of `dput(head(tweets.1.df))` to your post so we can see how your data structure looks like.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to transform something weird into character. Control the type of your corpus

Comment: Your code (starting from `mycorpus...`) works fine with your data on my machine (just had to delete one backslash when importing data in `href=\/...`). What happens when you manually try to turn your text to character `mytext <- as.character(tweets.1.df$text)`and then feed this text to `VectorSource` (although it should already be of type character according to your data structure)?